# Deleting blanks after characters in google sheet cells

Tags: google-sheets

let's say I have a google sheet columns that holds the following

- Phrase 1
- Phrase 2
- Phrase Word blabla 3

Now after the "2" of the second point there is a blank space.
How would I delete the blank space in every cell if it's the last character in the cell?

Best,
Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To** remove *ONLY* a single tailing space, last character in the cell use this formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(RIGHT(A2:A)=" ",LEFT( A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-LEN(RIGHT(A2:A)) ),A2:A))
```

Breakdown:
1 - logical_expression of the [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) function `IF(RIGHT(A2:A)=" "` to check if the last charachter is a space `" "` if `TRUE` then calculate the fonction `LEFT( A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-LEN(RIGHT(A2:A)) )` if not return the input.

2 - `LEFT( A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-LEN(RIGHT(A2:A)) )` to get all string before the last character which is space `" "` by subtracting the [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) length of a single space charachter of the input from the [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) lenght of input.

Formula
[image: Formula]

Output
[image: Output]

**To** remove *all additional spaces* dynamicaly in column `A:A` past this formula in cell `A2`.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(A2:A)))
```

Breakdown:
1 - [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en) function Removes leading, trailing, and repeated spaces in text.

2 - using [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) function To calculate only if the cells in `A` is not blank `""` like this `IF(A2:A="",[ Do nothing ],[ Execute the function ]`.

3 - [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) to  perform multiple calculations on one or more items in an array, in this case `A1:A`.

Input
[image: Input]

Formula
[image: Formula]

Output
[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Use the TRIM function - this removes trailing, leading and repeating space characters in cells.